# How can i add click event to pushpin in autodesk forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

How can I add a click event on pushpins to autodesk forge? In an [existing extension](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card), he opens the content for pushpin using the camera focus on it. I want to open it with click on pushpin.

But I add the pushpini to the model manually and translate the coordinates with the following code

```
var setData = function (event) {      
      var screenPoint = {
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY
      };
      if (screenPoint) {
        var n = normalize(screenPoint);
        var dbId = /*_viewer.utilities.getHitPoint*/ getHitDbId(n.x, n.y);
        if (dbId == null) return;
      }
    }

    function getHitDbId(x, y) {
      y = 1.0 - y;
      x = x * 2.0 - 1.0;
      y = y * 2.0 - 1.0;

      var vpVec = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, 1);
      var result = viewer.impl.hitTestViewport(vpVec, false);
      console.log(result);

      if (result) {
        dummyData.push({
          icon: Math.round(Math.random() * 3),
          x: result.point.x,
          y: result.point.y,
          z: result.point.z,
        });
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('newData', {
          'detail': dummyData
        }))
      } else {
        return
      }
      return result ? result.dbId : null;
    };

    function normalize(screenPoint) {
      var viewport = viewer.navigation.getScreenViewport();
      var n = {
        x: (screenPoint.x - viewport.left) / viewport.width,
        y: (screenPoint.y - viewport.top) / viewport.height
      };
      return n;
    }
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been taken care of in the original plugin - simply append your own handler in the click callbacks below where hit test on the markups is performed:

```
    this.onMouseMove = function(event) {
      if(this.line3d){
        this.update_DivLabel('onMarkupMove');
        this.updateHitTest(event);
      }
    }

    this.onClick = function(event) {
        this.updateHitTest(event);
        if (!this.hovered) return;
        this.selected = this.hovered; //
        //your own callback goes here
    }
```

And adjust here to fine tune hit test accuracy:

```
function markup3d(viewer, options) {
    this.raycaster.params.PointCloud.threshold = 5; // hit-test markup size.  Change this if markup 'hover' doesn't work
    this.size = 150.0; // markup size.  Change this if markup size is too big or small
```

The original live sample handles click as well by displaying a hoevering label:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not work. The problem is that the hover does not work when I am not directing the cursor. He takes a hover using the camera and I need to move the model to change the selected pushpin.

Comment: for getting hover on pushpin you need to do zoom on them and after that click somewhere on canvas.

Comment: like we went through in my answer try adjust `this.raycaster.params.PointCloud.threshold` to boost the hit test accuracy but got to admit i couldn't exactly get very satisfying hit rates either

Comment: I got some result. it works by double-clicking on the pushpin. In fact, this is how it changes the focus of the camera to it and it works. But this only works fine on large models where the points are far apart. And so I understand that this is not a solution, because not everyone has large models and points can be next to each other.

Comment: we did not miss your answer, I changed the value reached to some result.

Comment: i thinj i fised your live demo. You can see it [here](https://jsbin.com/juyohinode/edit?js,console,output)